# How to enable mysqli on official php:7.4 docker image

Tags: php, docker, mysqli

I have tried to enable mysqli on the official php docker image by writing and using a custom Dockerfile, like so:

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

However, the docker-php-ext-install command fails with the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/php_mysqli.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/php_mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/php_mysqli.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/php_mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

How do i enable mysqli on the official php docker image? And if mysqli is supposed to replace other deprecated php functions for connecting and using mysql, why is it not enabled by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mysql :

`RUN apt-get -y install php7.4-mysql`

If you use `docker-php-ext-install`, it is necessary to install the PHP package.

Comment: I receive: `E: Package 'php7.4-mysql' has no installation candidate` from running the install command.

Comment: Try `php-mysql`.

Search the package mysql for your linux distrib.

Comment: That did it. Thanks :)